# Can someone tell me what's wrong, when I run it the browsers says "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am learning Python on Treehouse and right now I am on the Flask Turorial. There is a part of how to build a social app. I watched the videos a few times and I typed the exact code in IDLE but when I run the app it runs correctly, then when I type http://127.0.0.1:8090 in the browser it says "The site can't be reached".
Does anyone know where is the problem?

I uploaded my code to GitHub so you can review it. Here's the link: https://github.com/nenadristov/social_app_treehouse/tree/master

Comment: your app is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and not on `http://127.0.0.1:8090`. You can change that in your `app.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your Port number. In app.py the Port mentioned is 8000 but you are trying to access 8090.
Try http://127.0.0.1:8000/